# How to "deep freeze" object like in JavaScript?

Tags: c++

As we know, in JavaScript, we can freeze an object in runtime such that it will be immutable, furthermore, we can recursively freeze its mutable members such that it can no longer be modified from now on. Is it possible to achieve similar thing in C++?

I am aware of that this will inevitably cause an overhead and I am OK with it. My biggest problem is my class will have public members, and it looks like there is no way to stop a non-const reference owner from changing a public member directly.

---

EDIT: I am going to describe the design problem I am facing and suggest some solution.

We want to parse a musical sheet (in MusicXML form) into our internal hierarchical data structure, after this, our business logic will use the data structures and retrieve needed info from it. Our internal data structure needn't and shouldn't be modified after the parsing procedure. Because parsing procedure is pretty complex, we cannot make everything const and we have to modify the object after creation, so the "freezing" idea is natural here to prevent unintended modification to our DS.

Some ideas I have:

1. Spam getters and setters in my classes, and add a `freezed` flag for every class. (Most straightforward, but not tidy.)
2. Use some accessor helper classes to achieve this read only limitation.
3. It is too complex, and it is not worthwhile to freeze the objects.

Comment: soooo just `const` ?

Comment: Use public getter/setters for properties and make fields private. In getters/setters you can develop own logic when it can/can't be modified.

Comment: If you want that, your class will *not* have public members. You need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), then post a question about the problem you're trying to solve by doing this. There is almost certainly a decent idiomatic solution to your ultimate problem that doesn't rely on emulating JavaScript.

Comment: To be clear, is what you want the possibility for a member of a class to mutate its constness during the lifetime of an object instance (start as mutable and become immutable later, maybe only one change?)?

Comment: @KamilCuk achieving the same thing with `const` in c++ that you can do with `freeze` in JavaScript might not always work easily, especially if it is about recursively making an object its members, and the members of those members `const`.

Comment: If an object is `frozen` and you attempt to use a non-const member function, what should happen?  Throw an exception?  Do nothing and ignore the call?  In C++, `const` is shallow.  Is freezing shallow?  C++ doesn't have reflection, so deep freezing would have to be done through code on a class-by-class basis.

Comment: @KamilCuk Constness is always my first choice but I am afraid it is not perfect in this case. You may want to check the question update

Comment: @molbdnilo Agree, that is what I feel like when posting this question, Let me change the question.

Comment: I don't understand why `const` isn't the answer here. Your parsing logic deals with a non `const` `MusicalSheet` object and fills it in. That gets passed to your business logic as a `const MusicalSheet&`. As long as you encapsulate the fields well enough (so you can't logically modify the data through `const` pointers to non `const` data), there's no issue.

Comment: Ok, I have an idea of how to make this work.  If you have a class with public members you can make this class and change it as much as you like while parsing.  If the external-facing class is a proxy then it can control access for clients - but that doesn't add anything to the actual class (have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl ).  The other thing you can do is make all the members private and have getters only plus make a builder class a friend so that it can use the private members directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use `const`.

Say you have a class `MusicalSheet`. You can define getters and setters for whatever data you want. Make the setters `const` so you can't call them on a `const` object or reference.

```
class MusicalSheet
{
public:
    void setNote(size_t position, Note note);
    const Note& getNote(size_t position) const;

private:
    // Data members
};
```

Then you have your parsing logic and business logic, and `main` to tie them together:

```
void parseMusic(MusicalSheet &sheet, Input &input);
void businessLogic(const MusicalSheet &sheet);

int main()
{
    MusicalSheet sheet;
    Input input(...);

    parseMusic(sheet, input);
    businessLogic(sheet);
}
```

Your parsing function has a non const reference to the object, so it can call `setNote` to fill in the data. The business logic can only access `getNote` as it's marked `const`. And `getNote` returns a `const` reference, so the inner object is also not modifiable by the business logic.

The example `MusicalSheet` class is obviously over simplified, and can in fact be replaced with just a `std::vector<Note>`, using `operator[]` to get and set the individual notes (along with many other functions). Like `MusicalSheet`, with a `const` vector you can only access the inner objects, not modify them.

Read the documentation on the [const type qualifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) and [const-qualified member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-_and_volatile-qualified_member_functions)

One caveat with `const` is pointers. Making an `int*` const will give you a `int* const`, which is a constant pointer to a non-constant int. This is also true for smart pointers.

To get around it you can do something like this:

```
class DataHolder
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Data>& getData() { return _data; }
    const Data* getData() const { return _data.get(); }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Data> _data;
};
```

Now with a `DataHolder` you can reassign the pointer (e.g. `dataHolder.getData() = std::make_unique<Data>(...);`), but with a `const DataHolder` all you can do is access a `const Data*`.

Comment: I understand how ```const``` keyword works in C++. However, the musical sheet is so complex and there are many non-local notation, so the data structure is not completely hierarchical. Actually, we have many (smart) pointers such that users can jump around in DS to extract needed info. Those pointers are also needed when parsing so those pointers can't be pointers to const object.

Comment: As a result, compile-time constness will inevitably be broken once we want to navigate through the pointers, unless the users of DS also declear all handlers they have to be const in their code.

Comment: Anyway, you are right, constness is the correct approach here. If my colleagues shoot their own feet by dropping the constness that could be added, then it's their fault, not mine :)

Comment: @LIUQingyuan I updated my answer with an example of how to solve the problem for pointers.

Comment: See also [propagate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const)

Comment: @Caleth Neat. Hopefully that will make it into a standard soon.

Comment: @Caleth Fancy one! I like it but we can't use it as of now cuz we don't use experimental features. Hope it will be in standard soon.